# jQuery append icon only once

Tags: append

I'd like to append an icon on a table row data, but only once on window resize. The problem is that whenever I resize the window its appends the icon multiple times. This is the code I have, that works when the window is resized once.

```
    $(window).on('resize', function(e) {
        if ($(window).width() < 600) {  
            $('td.sorting').append('<i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull right fa-2x"></i>'); 
        }

    });
```

Does anyone have a better solution please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//You must add a mark when youYou must add a mark when you've added the icon
$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {  
          if(!$(this).data('addedIcon')) {
            $('td.sorting').append('<i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull right fa-2x"></i>');  
            $(this).data('addedIcon', true);
          }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's probably something I have in the CSS.